# Windows Phone Project Visual Studio 2013, can't open due to update required (Despite latest update being applied)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `windows phone project` which I can't open due to an update being required by `Visual Studio 2013`.

I have applied the latest update and done a system restart but I'm still told I can't access my project because I still need an update.

Has anyone got any experience with this? I have applied the latest updates in the Visual Studio Gallery but still no luck.

Here's a picture of how the project looks:

[image]

Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
install javascript nuget package
```

Comment: Still asking for an update I'm afraid, got any other suggestions?